# Resize image using another website

Tags: php

Having exhausted the possibility of solving the image resizing issue I posted in [Problems rotating and resizing large images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34512904/problems-rotating-and-resizing-large-images), due to having a shared server on which I can't alter the memory allowance or install additional image handling libraries, I wondered if there would be a way for me to use an external website to resize the image and pass it back to my PHP script?

Eg:

```
$mylargeimage = "http://www.mywebsite.com/uploads/largephoto.jpg";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.imageresizingsite.com/resizethis.php?src=" . $mylargeimage . "&scale=50");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true)

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I don't know if this would work - nor have I found a website which actually resizes images - but is this approach a possibility and does anyone know of a website which would resize images using this kind of approach?

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you want to resize the image yourself: 
(i can't test the code right now, i haven't got a local server currently)

```
$image = $link_to_image;
$source_image = imagecreatefromfile($image);
$source_imagex = imagesx($source_image);
$source_imagey = imagesy($source_image);
$crop_measure = min($source_imagex, $source_imagey);


$to_crop_array = array('x' =>0 , 'y' => 0, 'width' => $crop_measure, 'height'=> $crop_measure);
$thumb_im = imagecrop($source_image, $to_crop_array);

imagejpeg($thumb_im, NULL, 80); //This may change, see the link below in this answer to see the right way to do that (it change because of extension) 
}

?>
```

[Link that maybe help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10247150/4904377)

Remember that if you need to resize images from php, you should have the gd driver installed on the server, to see if you have them, make a php_info() call in a empty page

IF YOU WANT TO DO THAT REMOTELY
[THIS SHOULD HELP YOU](http://embed.ly/docs/api/display/endpoints/1/display/resize)

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I run into the same issue which is that I don't have enough free memory on the server to manipulate the image, and I can't increase the memory allowance because it's a shared server.

Comment: hope this can help! If you prefer to do that on another "site" try searching "image resizer api" on the web